# Dynamically create class definition including decorator with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Is it possible to generate class definition with decorators dynamically like following?
(The code does not actually work, but shows what I would like to achieve)
*This code contains TypeORM's decorator, but the essense of the question does not involve the library knowledge.

```
const classGenerator = (jsType: string, dbType: string, nullable: boolean) => {
  return class {
    @Column({ type: dbType, nullable })
    val: jsType;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but everything you use as types must be provided as a generic parameter:

```
const classGenerator = <jsType extends string>(dbType: string, nullable: boolean) => {
  return class {
    @Column({ type: dbType, nullable })
    val: jsType;
  };
};
```